# Applying the height of a div element to be as much as the the div within

Tags: html, css

What my CSS structure consists of is, basically, a container,which contains the background and side borders.. Within this container, I inserted my div elements(header,navigation, sidemenus..) On the bottom of that, I included my footer(which is in no importance now). My problem is, that I can't really adjust the height of the container.. I want it to be automatically as much as the longest div element inside it(the center column usually). The picture below represents all of this with fixed height of 400px.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2qnw8pv&s=8#.U5nZAyhqNuB

Here is the CSS code:

The container:

```
#pagewidth{
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    text-align:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 400px;
    border-top: 1px solid #354350;
    border-left: 1px solid #354350;
    border-right: 1px solid #354350;
    background-color:#0f0f0f;
    }
```

The header:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height:150px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-image:url('images/logo2.png');
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #354350; */
    }
```

Columns structure:

```
    #columns {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    }

 #leftmenu {
    position: relative;
    width: 17%;
    float: left;
    }

#twocols {
    position: relative;
    width: 81%;
    float: right;
    }

#centercol {
    position: relative;
    width: 67%;
    float: left;
    }
#rightmenu {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    float:right;
    }
```

and finally, the footer:

```
#footer{
 height: 30px;
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 overflow: auto;
 background-color: #F8F4F4;
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 2px solid #E8E8E8;
```

}

P.S - I haven't added the navigation and table-like designed columns because I thought they had no relevance in the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `height` attribute. Like so

```
#pagewidth{
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
text-align:left;
margin: 0 auto;
border-top: 1px solid #354350;
border-left: 1px solid #354350;
border-right: 1px solid #354350;
background-color:#0f0f0f;
}
```

And ad a class for example called `clearfix` to your `HTML`.

```
<div id="pagewidth" class="clearfix">
```

Then add this to your `CSS`

```
  .clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

More information about this and crashing floats [here](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: I tried, it appears until the top of the first box-like elements.

Comment: The Clearfix thing made it. Thanks a lot!